# Switch off booktabs for one table only

Tags: tables, spacing, rules, booktabs

I am using the `booktabs` package in basically all my papers to present tables with results or descriptive statistics. However, I need to show a schematic choice in a table, and for that I need a proper grid with continuous vertical lines. `booktabs` only allows for vertical lines with spaces in between and lines do not intersect.  This is turned on automatically for all tables.

I'd rather not write something in `tikz` just for that, I have the table and it looks nice without `booktabs`, however then the rest of the tables in the paper looks bad.

So my question essentially is how can I switch off `booktabs` within/for a specific `tabular` environment?

To illustrate the issue

[image]

Comment: [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) only provide a number of rule macros for use in `tabular`. If you don't use them, you can make a regular `tabular` in the usual way. So, there's no need to "turn off `booktabs`" - just don't use the provided rules for that table.

Comment: @Werner Shouldn't this just be an answer?

Comment: rephrased the question to be more clear. booktabs automatically changes the way vertical lines are drawn. I need a proper grid with continuous lines, booktabs changes this such that there are no intersections.

Comment: booktabs doesn't change the vertical rules, the gaps appear if you use booktabs constructs like `\midrule` if you use standard latex `\hline` it should touch the vertical rules.

Comment: true, completely forgot about that...the forest for the trees. if you add this as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Comment: @ilprincipe: This question might benefit from being rephrased as requiring the use of the regular `booktabs` rules (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule`, ...) but *without* the vertical gaps in vertical rules. Is that what you're after? Otherwise you just don't have to use the `booktabs` rules and things will be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gaps of the vertical lines are caused by the special rule commands `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\bottomrule` of package `booktabs`. If you are not using them, then there are not gaps,
Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|l}
  \toprule
  with & booktabs \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  without & booktabs' & rules \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l}
  \toprule
  again & with & booktabs \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, there's no need to pull the old switcheroo with [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). You can use regular `\hline`s as-is. If you wish to mix `booktabs`'s *and* vertical rules, you need some more bravado.

The [`booktabs` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) mentions (in section **4 Abuse of the new commands**, p 4-5):

> In a rare fit of tolerance, though, I have also provided the command
>
> ```
> \specialrule{<wd>}{<abovespace>}{<belowspace>}
> ```
>
> where all three arguments are mandatory (I couldn’t be bothered to program in
>   defaults). If you use this frequently, you have misunderstood the purpose and
>   content of the guidelines given above. A preceeding rule does not add its default
>   space below, and a following rule adds no space above itself, so you get exactly
>   the space speciﬁed in the arguments.

In fact, `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` can be replicated using `\specialrule`:

```
\newcommand{\bttoprule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{\belowrulesep}}
\newcommand{\btbottomrule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{\belowbottomsep}}
```

that inserts a "horizontal rule" of width `\abovetopsep` [`\aboverulesep`] *above* (actually a vertical skip), a rule of width `heavyrulewidth` in the *middle* and a "horizontal rule" of width `\belowrulesep` [`\belowbottomsep`] *below*. To see that this is indeed the case, consider:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\bttoprule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{\belowrulesep}}
\newcommand{\btbottomrule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{\belowbottomsep}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \toprule
  with & booktabs & rules \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \bttoprule
  with & updated & rules \\
  \btbottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

With this in mind, we can remove the vertical skips inserted below [above] the `\bttoprule` [`\btbottomrule`] and supplement the regular content with a strut (let's call it `\btstrut`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\newcommand{\btstrut}{\rule%
  [\dimexpr-.3\normalbaselineskip-\aboverulesep]% depth
  {0pt}% width
  {\dimexpr\normalbaselineskip+\aboverulesep+\belowrulesep}}% height
\newcommand{\bttoprule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\abovetopsep}{0pt}}
\newcommand{\btbottomrule}{\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{0pt}{\belowbottomsep}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \toprule
  with & booktabs & rules \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
  \bttoprule
  \btstrut with & updated & rules \\
  \btbottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

However, this would be a long-winded way of avoiding the solid use of `booktabs` in the first place. Moreover, one would require different struts for interior `tabular` row content that have a `\bttoprule` [`\btbottomrule`] but no `\btbottomrule` [`\bttoprule`].